# css hover: эфект (для списка)

Tags: html, css, hover, span

Доброго времени суток всем!
Делая верстку столкнулся с тем, что не могу сделать hover эффект как указано в дизайне (ниже прикрепил часть скрина), так же приложил код который уже есть. 
Возможно кто то подскажет реализацию подобного эффекта без участия псевдоэлемента after, а с использованием например .
Буду благодарен вашей помощи!

```css
.left__blocks {
  min-height: 237px;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 7px rgba(67, 80, 102, 0.09);
  border-radius: 20px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  margin-bottom: 19px;
  max-width: 100%;
}
.status__project {
  width: 230px;
  }
.title__block {
  color: #435066;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 700;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 13px;
}
.line__desing {
  width: 96px;
  height: 4px;
  border-radius: 0 2px 2px 0;
  background-color: #0cdab8;
  left: 0;
}
ul.status__projet__list {
color: #435066;
list-style: none;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 14px;
font-size: 14px;
font-weight: 400;
line-height: 31.96px;
 transition: all 300ms;
}
.status__pay {
  position:relative;
      align-items: center;
    display: flex;
    transition: all 200ms ease;
}
.status__pay::after {
  content: "";
  min-width: 14px;
  min-height: 14px;
  right: 15px;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 7px;
  background-color: #535fde;
}
a li.status__pay:hover {
  transform: translateX(10%);
  transition: all 300ms ease;
  color: #7800e2;
  font-weight: 500;
}
```

```html
<div class="status__project left__blocks">
  <!-- // Блок статуса   -->
  <div class="title__block">Тип</div>
  <div class="line__desing"></div>
  <ul class="status__projet__list">
    <a href="#">
      <li class="status__pay">Новые</li>
    </a>
    <li class="status__new">Новые</li>
    <li class="status__skam">Новые</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(!) Осторожно, пиксели.

Задолбался переделывать ваш код, сделал с нуля, наверно сможете уже допилить его к себе)

Вместо кругляшек выступают обычные блоки с border-radius: 50%. А при наведении - убираю радиус бордеров справа.

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/OPTlMUS/n8ct76z2/)

```css
.bubu {
  padding: 5px 0; 
  border: 1px solid red; /* для наглядности */
  width: 160px; 
  position: relative; /* У кругляшек абсолютная позиция. 
  А этот фрагмент у родительского блока, будет удерживать их внутри */
  cursor: pointer;
  box-sizing: border-box;/*Это важно, чтобы при наведении padding не сдвигал блок*/
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.bubble {
  width: 16px; height: 16px; position: absolute;
  right: 15px; top: 6px;
  background-color: #236; border-radius: 8px;
  transition: 0.2s;
}

.bubu:hover .bubble {
  right: 0; width: 31px; 
  /* собственная ширина была 16, right: 15; 
   * Теперь right: 0; а ширина стала 16 + 15 px
   */
  border-radius: 8px;
  border-top-right-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
  background-color: #bc007c;
}

.bubu:hover {
  padding-left: 15px;
  color: #bc007c;
}
```

```html
<ul class="status">
  <a href="#">
    <li class="bubu">Новые<div class="bubble"></div></li>
  </a>
  <li class="bubu">Бубу<div class="bubble"></div></li>
  <li class="bubu">Чебурашки<div class="bubble"></div></li>
</ul>
```

P.s. вместо padding-left, padding-right по-отдельности, можно прописать сразу 4 числа в один. Начиная с верхнего padding-top, дальше всё идет по стрелке часов:

```
padding: верх право вниз лево;
____________

padding-top: 10px;
padding-right: 20px;
padding-bottom: 30px;
padding-left: 40px;

сокращается до:

padding: 10px 20px 30px 40px;
```

Та же история и с margin. А если там всего два числа, первая означает верх-вниз, второе: лево-право.

Comment: Доброго времени суток! 
Очень благодарен, благодаря вам теперь я знаю как это сделать и смогу повторить у себя!
Очень признателен за потраченное время!

Answer (score 1):

Ты заложил

в ссылку, значит :hover нужно делать для ссылки! Попробуй так, у меня лично сработало.

```css
.left__blocks {
  min-height: 237px;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 7px rgba(67, 80, 102, 0.09);
  border-radius: 20px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  margin-bottom: 19px;
  max-width: 100%;
}
.status__project {
  width: 230px;
  }
.title__block {
  color: #435066;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 700;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 13px;
}
.line__desing {
  width: 96px;
  height: 4px;
  border-radius: 0 2px 2px 0;
  background-color: #0cdab8;
  left: 0;
}
ul.status__projet__list {
color: #435066;
list-style: none;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 14px;
font-size: 14px;
font-weight: 400;
line-height: 31.96px;
 transition: all 300ms;
}
.status__pay {
  position:relative;
      align-items: center;
    display: flex;
    transition: all 200ms ease;
}
.status__pay::after {
  content: "";
  min-width: 14px;
  min-height: 14px;
  right: 15px;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 7px;
  background-color: #535fde;
}
a li.status__pay:hover {
  transform: translateX(10%);
  transition: all 300ms ease;
  color: #7800e2;
  font-weight: 500;
}
```

```html
<div class="status__project left__blocks">
  <!-- // Блок статуса   -->
  <div class="title__block">Тип</div>
  <div class="line__desing"></div>
  <ul class="status__projet__list">
    <a href="#">
      <li class="status__pay">Новые</li>
    </a>
    <li class="status__new">Новые</li>
    <li class="status__skam">Новые</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Один вариант - не transform, а padding:

```css
a li.status__pay:hover {
  padding-left: 25px;
  transition: all 300ms ease;
  color: #7800e2;
  font-weight: 500;
}
```

Comment: Благодарю за ответ, но элемент, должен трансформироваться к краю, и при этом оставаться на былой позиции